# React native the method onChangeText does not work

Tags: reactjs, react-native, function

I am trying to create a function called onHandleWork that takes an input , then I take an input from onChangeText if that input === this.state.count I want that the clock resets however when the clock reach this.state.count nothing happens what are your thoughts?

```
import React from 'react'
import {Button, StyleSheet,Text,View,TextInput} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  appContainer: {

    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',

  },

  counts: {
    fontSize: 48,
  }
})

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      count: 0,
      start: true,

    }
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <View style={styles.appContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.counts}>{this.state.count}</Text>
        <Button onPress={() => this.onButtonStop()} title="stop"/>
        <Button onPress={() => this.onButtonStart()} title="start"/>
        <Button onPress={() => this.onClear()}title="clear"/>
        <TextInput  onChangeText={((value) => this.onHandleWork(value) )} keyboardType="phone-pad"  placeholder="time of work"/>
        <TextInput placeholder="enter your rest time"/>
      </View>
    )
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    setInterval(this.inc,1000)
  }

  onButtonStop(){
    clearInterval(this.state.count);
    this.setState({start: false})
  }

  onButtonStart(){
    clearInterval(this.state.count);
    this.setState({start: true})
  }

  onClear(){
    this.setState({
      count:0,
      start: false,
    })
  }

  onHandleWork(value) {
    if (this.state.count === value) {
      clearInterval(this.state.count);
      this.setState({
        count: 0,
        start: false,
      })
    }
  }





  inc = () => {
    if (this.state.start) {
      this.setState(PrevStep => ({
        count: PrevStep.count + 1
      }))
    }
  }


}
```

here is an Image that shows the problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQnwB.png)

I want to make it work when the clock is running

Comment: Because `value` is a string and `count` is a number.

Comment: how can I Transform value to int?

Comment: Try `Number.parseInt(value)`. So, change the if condition in the parentheses to `this.state.count === Number.parseInt(value)`

Comment: the error still persist

Comment: What is the error? Does it log something?

Comment: the same error as before maybe there is others bugs

Comment: does not execute the reset

Comment: I think is because the method onChangeText does not accept int as arguments what do you think?

Comment: I tested it and it works fine for me. Can you also try changing `Number.parseInt(value)` on `Number(value)`?

Comment: Not yet, do you input the value in snack? could you post the answer sir

Comment: if (this.state.count === Number(value))

Comment: Everything works fine for me with `Number(value)`. Make sure you are putting the correct number in the input. The number changes every second and you should type the number *current* value

Comment: It works when this.state.count is in stops

Comment: could you give me some advice please to make it work when the clock is running